# Capture Provisioning time in Performance testing

Tags: performance, load-testing

I have a situation in my application where I need to wait and note the provisioning time of a Virtual Machine (The time taken when the order got accepted and the time it is available for usage).

How can I note the provisioning time? In my orders page I have an 'In-Progress' state of the order when it is accepted and the 'Completed' state when the Virtual machine is available. Moreover, I have a resources tab as well where I can check the state change.

I am using Web Performance Load testing. If anyone having a solution to this please guide me. I am using both techniques in Web Performance Load testing, Real browser and Virtual Browser.

I am using Web Performance Load Testing tool - http://www.webperformance.com/

Comment: Are you sending out requests for several VMs at once? If its just one at a time, you don't really need a load-testing tool. Something like Selenium, or even some browser plugins that look for changes in a page will suffice. How is your resources tab updated? Is it a push notification? or do yo have to refresh the page?

Comment: This is almost certainly a white box testing scenario and you have not provided sufficient information about the environment, platform or implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio's Web Performance and Load Testing facilities.

Enclose the relevant requests in a "transaction". To do this, open the context (right-click) menu of the first request of those to be timed. Select "Insert transaction..." and fill in the form.

Comment: No. I am not using Visual Studio's web performance and load testing facilities. I am using Web Performance Load tester. It is a separate tool. Follow the link. http://www.webperformance.com/

Comment: @JarreeArhamShahid then please add tags and descriptions into your question to make it clear which tool you are using. The terms used in your question are generic, they might be applied to many tools.

Comment: Sorry for that! Ill make it clearer next time i post a question.

Comment: @JarreeArhamShahid No problem, but please edit this question to make it clear. Other people may not read your first comment on my answer, so they may make the same wrong interpretation that I made.